# Mail client fails through TOR SOCKS5 proxy with authentication failure

Tags: email, proxy, pop3, socks, tor

Happening for all POP, IMAP & SMTP protocols with or without SSL.

```
* Account '***': Connecting to POP3 server: ***:110...
[DATE TIME] POP< +OK Dovecot ready.
[DATE TIME] POP> USER ***
[DATE TIME] POP< +OK
[DATE TIME] POP> PASS ********
[DATE TIME] POP< -ERR [AUTH] Authentication failed.
*** error occurred on authentication
*** Authentication failed
```

A direct connection without `TOR SOCKS5 proxy` works without any issues at all. The same is happening for any mail client I tried with like ThunderBird, FoxMail, etc.

The same `TOR SOCKS5 proxy`

- HTTP[S] is working
- IRC is working

Deployed `TOR SOCKS5 proxy` with Docker.

Comment: Tell your mail client to refuse plaintext and validate certs, that should rule out a few possible problems.

Comment: @anx "with or without SSL" / "Plaintext or encrypted" = Not working! The same configuration works without the SOCKS5.

Comment: Please clarify version, configuration, and specifically the library version involved in the socks5 magic (there is a remote chance you are hitting a recent change in behaviour or regression from whatever your distributor did about a recently fixed curl proxy bug).

Comment: @anx I am using peterdavehello/tor-socks-proxy: https://hub.docker.com/r/peterdavehello/tor-socks-proxy/